# Why my Gamma Correction Filter function doesn't work fine? (Haskell)

Tags: image, haskell, image-processing, pixel

I've found following gamma correction formula, but picture doesn't change depending on coefficient `n` (it always looks like colors just very distorted).

```
gamma :: Double  -> Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8
gamma n = pixelMap $ \(PixelRGBA8 r g b a) -> PixelRGBA8 (y r) (y g) (y b) a
  where y p = ((p `pxDiv` 255) `pxPow` (1/n)) `pxMult` 255
```

Where

```
rounding :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
rounding a = floor (a + 0.5)

pxMult :: Pixel8 -> Double -> Pixel8
pxMult p x = rounding $ fromIntegral p * x

pxPow :: Pixel8 -> Double -> Pixel8 
pxPow p x = rounding $ fromIntegral p ** x

pxDiv :: Pixel8 -> Double -> Pixel8 
pxDiv p x = rounding $ fromIntegral p / x
```

are done for operations with `pixel` type.
This code uses `JuicyPixels` library.

Comment: Where did you find the formula? The `Pixel8` type is probably not precise enough to handle ``p `pxDiv` 255``. You should use `Double` instead as the output of the 3 `px` functions, and don't use `rounding` until the end.

Comment: @4castle do you mean place rounding function outside the `px-`functions? Like this: `... PixelRGBA8 (rounding $ pxMult .....) (..) (..) (..) ...`?

Comment: Like this: `y p = rounding $ ((fromIntegral p / 255) ** (1 / n)) * 255`

Comment: I had to say that with other order of functions applications inside `y p` function the resulting picture was changing depending on `n`, but pictures was distorted or almost black with different `n` values.